# The Google Cloud Logging driver for Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-logging

I'm not able to authenticate the google cloud driver `gcplogs` for Docker despite the fact that I've set the env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path/file where the JSON credentials of my service account is. The error message is the following:

```
ERROR: for oncrm_oncrm_1  Cannot start service oncrm: failed to initialize logging driver: google.DefaultTokenSource: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

The configuration I'm using on docker-compose is:

```
logging:
      driver: gcplogs
      options:
        gcp-project: "gcloud-project-id"
        gcp-meta-name: "prod-helpsec-01"
        labels: "app"
```

The enviroment I'm trying to run the docker container is:

- `docker-ce v18.03`
- `docker-compose v1.21.0`
- `Ubuntu 17.10`

Comment: Well, apparently the daemon needs the env var on the systemd config. So this is solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
google.DefaultTokenSource: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

I've had the same problem as above when I've run docker services with **gcplogs** logging driver.

**This is my solution of problem:**

On the host machine:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

Create file:

/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-service-override.conf

with this content:

```
[Service]
Environment="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/root/gcp-logging-service-cridentials.json"
```

Restart docker service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

**Useful links:**

1. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
2. https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd
3. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/

Comment: awarding you for providing a detailed explanation of the solution I found by myself.

Comment: Any idea how to do this with Docker for Mac?