# Failed to initialize logging driver: unable to connect or authenticate with Google Cloud Logging

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-container-optimized-os

**To do:**  Send logs to Google Logs Viewer from docker container.

**Faced Error**
I followed this article: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/
and executed `docker run --log-driver=gcplogs nginx`

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: unable to connect or authenticate with Google Cloud Logging: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission.
```

**OS:** Container Optimized OS cos-81-12871-1196-0

I also tried this [The Google Cloud Logging driver for Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983216/the-google-cloud-logging-driver-for-docker) with service account with `log.admin` and `log.writer` role

How do I send the logs to Stackdriver/Google Cloud Logging

Comment: Where are you running your container?

Comment: I hope documentation [1] could be helpful for you from where we are getting step by step procedures:
[1] https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere running the container in COS

Comment: @ShafiqI I tried with this documentation. It gives me this error : `docker: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: unable to connect or authenticate with Google Cloud Logging: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission.`

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your COS VM? perform a `gcloud compute instances describe --zone=yourZone instanceName`

Comment: @GamerAtmos: We need to have listed access scopes [1] in VM levels:
[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#scopes

Comment: @ShafiqI Thanks! This solved the problem for me. If you locked down the default GCE service account like me, you'll need to explicitly add the "Logs Writer" role.